# Change select box css on click option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to add a class to the `select` element depending on what `option` is selected.

**HTML**

```
<select class="wordpress">
  <option value="1" class="wordpress">Hello</option>
  <option value="2" class="joomla">2222</option>
  <option value="3" class="wordpress">33333</option>
  <option value="4" class="joomla">44444</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select{
  margin-top:50px;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:30px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.wordpress{
  background:url('http://muabanraovat.com/images/imgWordpress32.png') no-repeat center left transparent;
  padding-left:35px;
}
.joomla{
  background:url('https://a6a8g7g5.ssl.hwcdn.net/icons/22/216447/icon.png') no-repeat center left transparent;
  padding-left:35px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('select').change(function(){
        $(this).removeClass().addClass('wordpress');
    });
});
```

CSS Deck: http://cssdeck.com/labs/vmbenx2c

Comment: Asking for no negative votes is asking for negative votes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).removeClass().addClass(this.options[this.selectedIndex].className);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hL3x1owm/

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly  what I search.

Answer (score 0):

So use the text of the selected option.

Change

```
$(this).removeClass().addClass('wordpress');
```

to

```
var txt =  $(this).find("option:selected").text();
$(this).removeClass().addClass(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('select').change(function(){
        $(this).removeClass().addClass($(this).children('option[value="' +  $(this).val() + '"]').attr('class'));
    });
});
```

```css
select{
  margin-top:50px;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:30px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.wordpress{
  background:url('http://muabanraovat.com/images/imgWordpress32.png') no-repeat center left transparent;
  padding-left:35px;
}
.joomla{
  background:url('https://a6a8g7g5.ssl.hwcdn.net/icons/22/216447/icon.png') no-repeat center left transparent;
  padding-left:35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="wordpress">
  <option value="1" class="wordpress">Hello</option>
  <option value="2" class="joomla">2222</option>
  <option value="3" class="wordpress">33333</option>
  <option value="4" class="joomla">44444</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code also work. But @daniel-sunami 's code is easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

While you've already selected an answer, I thought I'd offer a further alternative, given that all answers thus far seem a little over-complicated. That said, I'd suggest:

```
$('select').change(function () {
  // setting the className of the changed <select> element 
  // to the className of the selected <option>
  // (this.selectedIndex gives theindex of the selected
  // <option> from among the options collection of the
  // <select> element:
    this.className = this.value;
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('select').change(function() {
    this.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
.wordpress {
  border-color: red;
}
.joomla {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="wordpress">
  <option value="1" class="wordpress">Hello</option>
  <option value="2" class="joomla">2222</option>
  <option value="3" class="wordpress">33333</option>
  <option value="4" class="joomla">44444</option>
</select>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/otz8b016/), for experimentation.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).
- jQuery:

  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).